# If $CC^*$ = $DD^*$ then C=DQ

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

If C and D be two m by l matrices and $CC^*$ = $DD^*$ then $C=DQ$ where $Q$ is a l by l unitary matrix .
If C and D  are  of order 1 then it is trivial  But for general case I was trying to use induction .
But I had faced slide problems . How can I do this for general case.

Comment: Hint: Use the polar decompositions (or singular value decompositions) of $C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $C$ spans the row space of $CC^*$.

Answer (score 0):

from SVD we get C = $U\Sigma V^*$ and D = $U_1\Sigma_1 V_1^*$ and so $CC^*$ = $DD^*$
and $U\Sigma V^*$$V\Sigma^* U^*$ = $U_1\Sigma_1 V_1^*$$V_1\Sigma_1^* U_1^*$
and $\Sigma\Sigma^*$ = $Q_1\Sigma_1\Sigma_1^*Q_1^*$ where $Q_1$ is a unitary matrix.
But we have to show that C = DQ i.e., $\Sigma$ = $Q_2\Sigma_1 Y$ where $Q_2$ and Y are unitary matrix .
How can I do this.